# Trouble building fovis_ros on Hydro

Tags: ros, fovis, fovis-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS Hydro and wanted to test fovis_ros with a Kinect, but I'm having trouble building the package.

Following the advice given in [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/163561/how-do-i-install-and-build-fovis_ros/) I executed the following commands :

> git clone
> https://github.com/srv/fovis.git

> git clone
> https://github.com/srv/libfovis.git

So I had the fovis and libfovis folders inside catkin_ws/src.

Then I tried building with catkin_make and got the following messages at the end:

> ...
>  [ 98%] Built target
> fovis_ros_generate_messages
>
> /home/ire/catkin_ws/src/fovis/fovis_ros/src/visualization.cpp:3:40:
> fatal error:
> libfovis/visual_odometry.hpp: No such
> file or directory 
> compilation
> terminated. 
> make[2]: ***
> [fovis/fovis_ros/CMakeFiles/visualization.dir/src/visualization.cpp.o]
> Error 1 
> make[1]: ***
> [fovis/fovis_ros/CMakeFiles/visualization.dir/all] Error 2 
> make: *** [all] Error 2
>
> Invoking "make" failed

I verified and the "visual_odometry.hpp" file is inside the libfovis/libfovis folder, like the rest of the files used by fovis_ros that don't seem to present an issue.

I tried building the libfovis library first, which gave no trouble and then adding fovis_ros but I got the exact same error. I also followed the advice from [issue #11](https://github.com/srv/fovis/issues/11) but the problem remained.

Here is the [complete log](https://gist.github.com/Athria/5bcd7c0564d324854cd7) in case it's more useful.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205522/trouble-building-fovis_ros-on-hydro/) by [Athria](https://answers.ros.org/users/20494/athria/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2015-03-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2015-03-24**:
Hi Athria, could you try to install ros-hydro-libfovis, remove libfovis from your workspace, delete build and devel directories and compile again?

**Comment by [Athria](https://answers.ros.org/users/20494/athria/) on 2015-03-24**:
Hello, than you! I tried that before installing libfovis from the git and I got errors, but I did it again (removing the libfovis, build and devel folders, then installing ros-hydro-libfovis an then catkin_make) but [this](https://gist.github.com/Athria/40c1165fbf002f5eee75) is what I got.

**Comment by [Athria](https://answers.ros.org/users/20494/athria/) on 2015-03-26**:
Hello, I'm sorry, that was indeed the problem. I was selecting Hydro on the Branch scroll bar and then copying the clone URL on the right, but I guess it was not the way to do it; this time I downloaded the zip instead and it compiled without errors.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you check if you are using hydro branch in fovis? Now our default is set on indigo.

You can simply switch the branch with "git checkout hydro".

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2015-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Athria](https://answers.ros.org/users/20494/athria/) on 2015-03-27**:
Thank you! I was doing it wrong, now it compiles perfectly.

**Comment by [Sai Anirudh Kondaveeti](https://answers.ros.org/users/22508/sai-anirudh-kondaveeti/) on 2015-05-26**:
I  am still facing the same problem. I installed libfovis via apt-get then I 'git clone' the repository and then checked out to hydro branch. but still I get [this](https://gist.github.com/Athria/40c1165fbf002f5eee75) error

**Comment by [Athria](https://answers.ros.org/users/20494/athria/) on 2015-05-27**:
Hello Sai, I don't know if it will help you but this is exactly what worked for me in the end: I deleted what I had from fovis, then I downloaded (manually, not by git clone) the two folders (libfovis and fovis) from the hydro branch in github to the catkin/src/ folder and then it compiled well.

**Comment by [Athria](https://answers.ros.org/users/20494/athria/) on 2015-05-27**:
I think when I was doing git clone it was downloading the indigo versions (I am really new with github) and that's why it wasn't working. I hope it helps

**Comment by [Sai Anirudh Kondaveeti](https://answers.ros.org/users/22508/sai-anirudh-kondaveeti/) on 2015-05-27**:
Thanks, but it didn't work for me.